# How can we construct the incenter of a triangle using a compass alone?

Tags: geometric-construction

To clarify, you have 3 non-collinear points $A$, $B$, and $C$. You have to get the incenter of the triangle $ABC$ using only a compass. Has it been solved/Is it possible?
(No straight edge)

Comment: Without straight edge, you can't copy lengths other than $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Comment: You can get coefficients of A,B, and C using some constructions.

Comment: I believe that it is known that given points $A, B, C$ and $D$, we can construct the intersection of the lines $AB$ and $CD$ with compass alone. (sorry, I don't have any reference at hand.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mathlove mentioned in the comments, the [Mohr-Masheroni Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohr%E2%80%93Mascheroni_theorem#Proof_approach) states that a compass suffices to perform all straight-edge constructions, as long as you don't need the edges drawn in at the end! So in theory yes, it is possible.

As a hint for building an explicit construction, since we can bisect angles easily (other than drawing in the final line), it suffices to construct the intersection of two straight lines passing through two pairs of given points. I found a [nice site](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/compass.shtml) which will guide you in that direction. The relevant construction is problem 11; solutions are linked on there too. Enjoy!